# How to change pad scroll speed?

Tags: touchpad, mouse-scroll

I'm coming from windows and having a hard time using ubuntu. The major problem for me is the pad. The sensitivity of the scroll is way too high and I can't reduce it. I've tried using imwheel but it doesn't work (it launch but even though I configured it does nothing). A friend of mine told me my pad might not be recognized by ubuntu, I am using a Lenovo Yoga Slim 7 in a dual boot (window 10 is the main OS), is this why I can't change the scroll sensitivity ?

Do you have a solution for this problem ? I really want to enjoy linux but I can't use it since every time I scroll it's sending me into oblivion.

Other question: do you know how to configure shortcuts for the pad (like 3 fingers to the left to go to previous page) ? That's not the topic of the post so it's not a problem if you don't know.

Answer (score -1):

You can change that in settings. Go to *Settings* -> *Mouse & Touchpad* and change *Touchpad Speed*.

[image]

Comment: That's only for mouse sensitivity. My problem is about mouse scrolling sensitivity. I may be missing something

Comment: Do you have another solution to my problem ?

Comment: try to use tweaks `sudo apt install tweaks` and go to keyboard and mouse menu

Comment: I have tried gnome-tweaks (I think this is what you were talking about) but still can't change the scroll sensitivity. But thank you for your answer, that has solved another of my problems :)