# Factory reset linux and resize the partition on dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, reset

I have a windows 10 / Ubuntu dual boot. When I made it, I've only set 20 Gb to Ubuntu thinking I would not use it much. But I have discovered that it is practical for coding. Unfortunately 20 Gb seems to not be enough, so I want to resize my linux partition. I have found some solutions, but they seem complicated.

So, since I don't know where does these 20 Gb come from (I installed many things in an attempt to make ubuntu more practical for me, even though [it didn't work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1457529/how-to-change-pad-scroll-speed)), I have decided to factory reset ubuntu by doing a complete installation on a bigger partition. But I am not sure how to do it.

I think it is possible to delete from windows my linux partition, resizing my windows partition to give more spare space, then plugging an installation usb drive to install ubuntu back.
Do you think it could work ? Or is there a better way to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can reinstall but there really is no need to do so. If you have the installation media to reinstall Ubuntu you have the tools to resize your existing installation. This is the process, it assumes your main Windows partition is adjacent to your Ubuntu root partition (if it isn’t post a screenshot of GParted with your disk selected):

1. Boot into Windows and use the disk management tool to resize your main Windows partition.
2. Boot the installation media but rather than choose install Ubuntu, choose Try Ubuntu.
3. In the live “Try Ubuntu” environment start the GParted app. Select the Ubuntu root partition and move/resize it to fill the space made available when you resized Windows. Don’t forget to click apply. It will then take GParted several minutes to complete the operation. It has to move your 20GB about on your disk.
4. Once the resize is complete you can reboot and make use of the extra space.

Good luck

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! I said that I need to reinstall because I don't know where these 20 GB come from. I want a clean install to finally have space available, and not 20 GB already taken from nowhere.

Comment: Perhaps you should ask a question about finding where those 20GB are on your computer. That would also reveal where you can make space for for an install with more space. Resizing Windows and reinstalling will work but I would say my answer is quicker and arguably easier. You wouldn’t need to install all the apps again that are taking up space